# Sawtooth generator using sine wave

Tags: pwm, simulation

I understand that sawtooth wave can be generated using a Modulo operator, but how do I generate a sawtooth wave using a sine wave in my simulation? This was more of a thought experiment.

Comment: If it's a sim thing, then why not use a sinewave voltage source and save all the fuss? Why would you generate a saw-tooth using a modulo operator when there are perfectly nice saw-tooth generators in every sim that I've ever used (good, bad and awful).

Answer (score 2):

Use a comparator to convert the sine wave to square wave, then an op amp integrator to change it to triangle waveform.